# What is a simple way to parse this specific xml using php?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Whay is a good way ( native way that works in both php 4 and 5 ) to extract the value from this xml string

```
<root>
<node1>
  <![CDATA[THE-TEXT]]>
</node1>
</root>
```

I wish to extract THE-TEXT content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple xml with a third parameter to  parse CDATA as Text:

look there: 
http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/09/22/quick-php-tip-how-to-parse-cdata-sections-using-simplexml/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$descriptions = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node1');
foreach($descriptions as $desc)
{
   echo "<div>".$desc->textContent."</div>";
}
```